# Create multiple json files with two lists using loops

Tags: python, json, list, loops

I want to ask how to make multiple JSON files with two lists?
let's say my input is:

```py
animal_list = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "fish", "chicken", "tiger"]
name_file = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

and output that I want is:

```
a.json -> "cat"
b.json -> "dog"
c.json -> "bird"
d.json -> "fish"
e.json -> "chicken"
f.json -> "tiger"
```

so file `a.json` contains `"cat"`, file `b.json` contains `"dog"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `zip()` function.  It allows you to iterate over the elements of multiple lists at the same time.

From there you can open each file as a `.json` file using an f-string to create the file name, and then write out the contents.

To write out to the JSON format, Python has the built-in `json` package.  This will ensure whatever Python object you want to save is formatted as proper JSON.  We will use the `json.dump` function, which takes your content and writes it to a file object.

```py
import json

animal_list = ["cat", "dog", "bird", "fish", "chicken", "tiger"]
name_file = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for fname, animal in zip(name_file, animal_list):
    with open(f'{fname}.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(animal, fp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import json

lst = ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
file_names = ["a", "b", "c"]

for file_name, content in zip(file_names, lst):
    with open(f"{file_name}.json", mode="w") as f:
        json.dump(content, f)
```

Basically you are zipping your two lists, then in each iteration you open a new file with the help of string formatting(you need to build the file's name) then you dump your objects with `json.dump` method.

Also do not use built-in names for your variable. I intentionally renamed `list` to `lst`.